# Using wp_editor in shortcode

Tags: shortcode, tinymce

I am building a plugin for frontend submission. I am using shortcodes API to display the form for content submission, but I am having troubles.
The problem is, wp_editor echoe's data, and shortcode should return data. When I integrate wp_editor like this:

```
$final_form .= wp_editor();
```

form does render, but not in the place but on top of the post content, where shotcode is included. Do you have any idea how would one use wp_editor in shortcode API? I don't wan't to bother with manually calling TinyMCE etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If a function `echo`s data, you can use [php output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to capture the `echo`ed output and return it instead

```
// Turn on the output buffer
ob_start();

// Echo the editor to the buffer
wp_editor();

// Store the contents of the buffer in a variable
$editor_contents = ob_get_clean();

// Return the content you want to the calling function
return $editor_contents;
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Could you show me an example code?

Comment: see edit above.

Comment: Isn't there a `get_wp_editor()` function? The output buffering looks a bit "hacky".

Comment: @CiprianPopescu there is no `get_wp_editor`, you can [look in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1807) and see exactly why output buffering is necessary in this case, nothing really hacky about it.

Comment: Thanks @Milo. I hope they'll add the option to return it instead of echoing it, without using output buffering. I'm using it for a front-end textarea.